How do I create a session that runs from friday till sunday the following week?
I understand that sessions can be written as such
For e.g.
session1 = "1000-1300"
or
session2 = "1000-1300:2"  for mondays only
However I am unable to write a session that runs from Friday 10:00 till Sunday 21:00. How can I go about doing that as I am coding the sessions for NQ futures market.
I tried writing this code but the session stops at 16:59 on Friday when trading stops for the week.
session1 = "1000 - 2100:6"

Stackoverflow is not a coding service. To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.

`"1000-2100:6" in this case, your session only contains Friday (6). You need to add Sunday (1) to the string as well.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

session1 = "1000-2100:16"

is_in_sess = bool(time(timeframe.period, session1))

bgcolor(is_in_sess ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)


